# Drush rsync command failed: No such file or directory

Tags: drush

I am new to use Drush.

this following is my .drushrc.php file

```
$aliases['server'] = array (
  'remote-host' => '162.243.78.240',
  'remote-user' => 'root',
);
$aliases["dxb"] = array (
  '#name' => 'dxb',
  'root' => '/var/www/dev/daxuebao',
);
```

I try to use this following command to sync local site to remote site

```
$ drush rsync @self @dxb
```

But it alert me:

```
rsync: mkdir "/var/www/dev/daxuebao" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(544) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]
Could not rsync from /Users/tangmonk/Sites/drupal/daxuebao// to      [error]
/var/www/dev/daxuebao/
```

It seems directory `/var/www/dev/daxuebao` do not exist, so I try to mkdir to my server :

```
$ mkdir /var/www/dev/daxuebao
```

The I type `$ drush rsync @self @dxb` again, But still above problem.
How to solved it?

Comment: So `/var/www/dev/daxuebao` definitely exists? As in, if you type `cd /var/www/dev/daxuebao` from your command line, it resolves to the expected location, and doesn't give a "No such file or directory" error?

Comment: thanks for your reply, ```/var/www/dev/daxuebao``` is exist. I updated my question, please help me.

Comment: As far as I can see the error message means either `/var/`, `/var/www/` or `/var/www/dev` doesn't exist on the remote server. Or maybe it's a permissions problem, couldn't really say from here I'm afraid

Comment: thanks for your reply, I run the rsync command as ```root``` user, Probably not a permissions issue. And the ```/var/```, ```/var/www/``` and ```/var/www/dev``` directory is exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why drush fails to rsync between my two local instances?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95194/why-drush-fails-to-rsync-between-my-two-local-instances)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the string containing the directory does not have extra blank spaces at the end. Trim it if possible. I was getting a similar message when I was using the option `--files-from=myDirList` and I have some spaces after the directory name inside the myDirList.